# Trying to print multiple columns to a row in .tsv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to print multiple columns from a scanned data file to a row. Here is my code:

```
#Searches for keyword
for line in data:
    if 'REMARK 300 BIOMOLECULE' in line: 
            bio = line.split()
            bio_molecules = bio[3] + bio[4] + bio[5] + bio[6] + bio[7] 

print("\t".join([pdb_name , bio_molecules]), file=datafile)    
datafile.close()
```

I am trying to get it so it will print columns into a .tsv file like the picture below.

[image: example]

This is the data file i'm reading from

[image: data file]

The problem is, when I'm scanning I get an error: Index out of range. Some of my files do not have 5 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab through the end of the list.

```
    bio_molecules = ','.join(bio[3:])
```

Comment: For some reason, everytime I scan through the files, it only provides one row of data. Also, thanks for the fix

Comment: That's because your print statement is not part of the loop, so it will only print the last line.  I suspect you want to indent it once.

Comment: I didn't realize how important it was to indent. thanks

Comment: In Python, indentation is syntax.  It's one of its most endearing features, and most confusing to those coming from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your task as follows

```
with datafile as open(datafile_name, 'w'):
    for pdb_name in pdb_names:
        with pdb as open(pdb_name, 'r'):
            for line in pdb:
                if 'REMARK 300 BIOMOLECULE' in line: 
                    print(pdb_name, '\t', ','.join(line.split()[3:]), file=datafile)    
                    # break # uncomment if only one REMARK per file is present
```